# Django: Template tag - the right way?

Tags: django, templatetags

I wrote the following simple template tag. I am wondering if there is any better way to write this without i = 0 and i + 1, or would you consider that as the good solution?

```
@register.simple_tag
def taxes(taxes):
    i = 0
    s = ""

    for tax in taxes:
        if i is not 0:
            s += ", "
        s += tax.name
        i += 1

    output = "Incl. {}".format(s)
    return output
```

As an alternative, I wrote this function in my template. It has the same outcome, but the template tag seemed more structured to me.

```
{% spaceless %}
{% for tax in form.initial.ticket.ticket_tax.all %}

    {% if forloop.first %}
        Incl.
    {% else %}
        ,
    {% endif %}

    {{ tax.name }} @
    {% get_tax_rate tax.percentage %}

{% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
```

[image: Output is Lorem ipsum @ ...]

**Update:**

That's the new version:

```
@register.simple_tag
def show_taxes(taxes):

    taxes = ', '.join('{} @ {} %'.format(
        tax.name,
        round(tax.percentage * 100, 2)
    ) for tax in taxes)

    if taxes:
        return 'Incl. {}'.format(taxes)
    else:
        return ''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template version seems fine. But if you do want to write a tag, there are much much simpler ways. For example:

```
taxes = ', '.join('{} @ {}'.format(tax.name, tax.percentage) for tax in taxes)
return 'Incl. {}'.format(taxes)
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks a lot for the tip to improve my code. That's what I was looking for. Just one question. The comma ', ' shouldn't be printed the first time, only the second, third, etc. 

Do you have any idea how to implement that?

Comment: That is what this code will do; it will insert commas *between* each result, so not before the first or after the last.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks a lot, that worked perfectly. As I have cases, where taxes will be empty, I had to add a check for that at the end. I updated it in my original post, is that how you would have done it as well?